# Android Studio Error: String literal in setText cannot be translated

Tags: android, android-studio

This is my first app and I'm having some trouble.

When I run the app it crashes and I don't know how to fix this error.

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {\
    TextView outputBottom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);

}
public void play_the_big_lie(View view) {
    the_big_lie.start();
    outputBottom.setText("ObamaCare, the big lie");
}
```

Comment: That is a warning, saying you should use strings.xml. Post your actual crash logs for the real reason

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> String literal in setText cannot be translated

This is not an error and you can safely ignore it (unless you need translation in your app).

It is simply a notification by Android Studio that you should be using a string resource file instead of a hard-coded string.

---

If I had to guess at the source of the issue since you did not post the logcat, it is this.

You can't use `findViewById` before `setContentView` because there is no view to "find".

Please try something like the following code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView outputBottom;    

    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        outputBottom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

There are two issues here.  First, you can't use `findViewById` until you have "created" things and have a view to find things with, so as the previous answer you want to separate them.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private TextView outputBottom;    

  protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
      super.onCreate(b);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      outputBottom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output);
  }

  ...
}
```

To set text, it's better not to "hardcode" with a string in quotes, but to create a string file and ask for it, which will look more like this:

```
outputBottom.setText(R.string.my_words);
```

Here are the [developer notes on strings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

If you're using Android Studio there are tutorials for how to make that happen.